# Where to put persistedState in Create-Store for saving redux store into localStorage

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I am trying to save my Redux-Store with browser LocalStorage. But I am not sure where to insert my persistedState. Here is my code.

```
import rootReducer from './Reducers';
import initialState from './Reducers/initialState';

import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;

const saveToLocalStorage = (state) => {
    try {
        const serializedState = JSON.stringify(state);
        localStorage.setItem('state', serializedState);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
};
const loadFromLocalStorage = (state) => {
    try {
        const serializedState = localStorage.getItem('state');
        if (serializedState == null) return undefined;
        return JSON.parse(serializedState);
    } catch (error) {
        return undefined;
    }
};
const persistedState = loadFromLocalStorage();
// I inserted my persistedState in createStore but I am getting an error ==> {Expected to be function}
const store = createStore(rootReducer, initialState, persistedState,  composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk)));


store.subscribe(() => saveToLocalStorage(store.getState()));

export default store;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends when do you need that state, but I imagine you'd want to load it on init, so it makes sense to merge it into your initial state:

```
const persistedState = loadFromLocalStorage();
const store = createStore(rootReducer, {
  ...initialState,
  ...persistedState
}, composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk)));
```

Comment: I wanted to load my ```ReduxState``` into ```LocalStorage```, so I do not lose user's info when page is refreshed.  thanks @clarity